# Why is it enough to prove the following sentence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable in $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ with values in  $E$. Let moreover $\phi : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded Borel mapping. Then we have:
        $$
  \int_{\Omega}\phi(X(\omega))\mathbb{P}(d\omega)=\int_E \phi(x)X_\#\mathbb{P}(dx)
  $$
Proof:
        It is enough to proove (1.1) when $\phi= \mathbf{1}_I$ and $I\in \mathcal{B}(E)$. In this case we have:
        $$\phi (X(\omega))=\mathbf{1}_{X^{-1}(I)}(\omega), \ \ \ \omega \in \Omega$$ 
        So
        $$\int_{\Omega}\phi(X(\omega))\mathbb{P}(d\omega)=\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(I))=X_\# \mathbb{P}(I)=\int_E \phi(x)X_\#\mathbb{P}(dx)$$

My question: why is it enough to proove this theorem for one specific function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- By the linearity of the integral, the identity also holds for simple functions (also known as elementary functions/step functions).
- For any non-negative measurable function $\phi: E \to \mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of simple functions such that $0 \leq f_n \leq \phi$ and $f_n \uparrow \phi$ (i.e. $f_n(x) \uparrow \phi(x)$ for all $x \in E$). Since we already know that the claim holds for each $f_n$, it follows from the monotone convergence theorem that the claim also holds for $\phi$.
- For arbitrary measurable $\phi$ consider the decomposition $\phi = \phi^+ - \phi^-$ and use again the linearity of the integral.

This reasoning is used very frequently in measure theory, a so-called monotone class argument.

Answer (score 0):

Often times for proofs like this, you first prove things for indicator functions of measurable sets, then for simple functions, then for all measurable functions.

Explicitly, let $\mathcal F = \{ \phi : E \to \mathbb R : \phi \text{ satisfies the desired properties }\}$.  If you can prove that $\mathcal F$ contains all indicator functions of measurable sets, is closed under linear combinations and is closed under monotone limits, than $\mathcal F$ contains all measurable functions (this is an example of a so-called Monotone Class Theorem). I guess they just took the last two steps for granted.

Edit: Just noticed that @saz posted the same thing a few minutes before me.